# How to write this type of code in "vim test.py"

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

```
"!spleeter separate -o output/ converted.mp3"
```

I want to add this code to my python file where I have converted the video file into an audio file and now I am separating the music from vocals. This code works properly on the command line but I am confused about how to use it in a VIM file so that it may run simply by running the command "python3 test.py".

Thank you in advance

Comment: [vi.se] might be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Barmar The question is about Python; it's about how to run an external program from a Python script and how to write such a script in `vim`.

Comment: That's not Python code.

Comment: Why do you need a Python script to run a shell command?

Comment: It's my research work task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run terminal commands in python use subprocess library in python.

```py
import subprocess 
subprocess.run(['!spleeter', 'separate', '-o', 'output/', 'converted.mp3'])
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but with little changes while trying in python we don't write the (!) sign.
import subprocess 
subprocess.run(['spleeter', 'separate', '-o', 'output/', 'converted.mp3'])

Comment: `!` is the `vim` command to run a shell command, it's not part of the shell command itself.

Comment: oh I am sorry. I didn't know that.